# JDownloader and same filename files

Tags: download, jdownloader

Using the program JDownloader v2 and the add-on packagizer, I want to download some pictures from a site but i have the following problem.
The filename is always the same. The parent folder name has the format "yymmdd"
For example:

```
https:// site-name.com /pictures /230410/pic_a.jpg
https:// site-name.com /pictures /230409/pic_a.jpg
https:// site-name.com/ pictures/ 230408/pic_a.jpg
```

How can I download the pictures without overwrite and without losing the information from which (date) folder is the picture.
What I want actually is the filename of the downloaded picture to be: pic_a_230410.jpg, pic_a_230409.jpg etc.

I tried to make a few rules in the packagizer but no luck.